# munmap_chunck(): invalid pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, global-variables

I have a program that I've written to do some data analysis, and this data is stored in a global structure called P. I allocate the memory for this structure in one function and then, since I need it for the entire program, don't call free until the very end of main. Malloc is not called in main because the size of the array is obtained from a file, so I figured that it made the most sense to read in the file and allocate the memory there, rather than doing all of it in main.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct DATA
{
    /* variables*/
} DATA;

DATA *P;
void function1(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    function1();
    /*do some stuff*/
    free(P);
    return 0;
}

void function1(void)
{
    if(!(P = (DATA *)malloc(nums * sizeof(DATA))))
    {
        printf("Error!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /*do stuff*/
}
```

Essentially, when I run my code, I get the error: munmap_chunck(): invalid pointer. I've done a bit of reading and it seems to be related to the function free.  I've also read that malloc and free should be called in the same function.  If this is the case, then my question is: since P is a global variable, why does it matter which function malloc and free are called in for this particular variable? If, in fact, the problem is not caused by malloc and free being called in different functions, does anyone have any advice on what it might be instead? Thank you very much!

Comment: You don't need to cast the result of `malloc` in C. `P = malloc(nums * sizeof(DATA))` is fine.

Comment: Oh, ok, cool. I'd always been taught that it was good to do, but I'd never really thought about why, to be honest. I'll have to look into that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem which occurs when you provide `free` a pointer which doesn't point to the start of an allocated memory block. For example, the code

```
int* something = malloc(sizeof(int)); // Allocate space for 1 int
...
free(something);
```

will work fine as you are providing `free` with the original pointer returned by `malloc`. However, if you do something like this:

```
int* something = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5); // Allocate space for 5 ints
...
something += sizeof(int); // Shift the allocated memory by 1 int
...
free(something);
```

Then `free` has been provided a pointer to somewhere in the middle of the allocated memory block. This means that essentially, `free` has no idea where the block starts or ends, therefore throwing an error. This can be fixed by storing the original pointer value in another pointer:

```
int* something = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
int* another_something = something; // `another_something` contains the same pointer value as `something`
...
something += sizeof(int); // `something` changes, `another_something` doesn't
...
free(another_something); // Free the original pointer
```

So, in your case, something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct DATA
{
    /* variables*/
} DATA;

/* Declare another DATA*, P1 */
DATA *P, *P1;
void function1(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    function1();
    /*do some stuff*/

    /* Free the original pointer, in P1 */
    free(P1);
    return 0;
}

void function1(void)
{
    if(!(P = (DATA *)malloc(nums * sizeof(DATA))))
    {
        printf("Error!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Store the original value of `P` in P1 */
    P1 = P;

    /*do stuff*/
}
```

Lastly, please fix your naming conventions. `P` and `function1` are awful names.

Comment: Great, thanks! That seems to have fixed it. As for the names, they are terrible names and not what I actually use lol, I just went with them for this to be as simple as possible.